# Remove container padding for BottomSheet Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, padding, bottom-sheet

Have a space under the BottomSheet, I think it's the navigation bar what I hide before. I want remove this space. In Layout Inspector I noticed the R.id.container (FrameLayout) of BottomSheet have padding 48dp, bu idk what is it. Tried remove it, but it doesn't work. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdKRe.png)
[Layout Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdygn.png)

```
private void showAndHandleBottomSheetDialog() {
    final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_layout);
    bottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

    RadioGroup radioGroupTip = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.tip_list_custom);
    ImageView buttonClose = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.button_close);
    ArrayList<TipItem> tipItemList = new ArrayList<TipItem>(Arrays.asList(TipItem.values()));

    if (checkedButtonID != -1) {
        radioGroupTip.check(checkedButtonID);
    }

    bottomSheetDialog.show();

    buttonClose.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        checkedButtonID = radioGroupTip.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
    });}
```

Comment: Kindly share your code. It's difficult to interprete

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The below approach will hide the systembars, if your problem's cause is the navigationbar then it should solve it.

```
private void showAndHandleBottomSheetDialog() {
    final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    // here you need to inflate your view and hide system bars, then set it.
    // The added code for kotlin, kindly convert it to java
    val bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_layout,
            view?.findViewById(R.id.IdOfYourDialogParent)
        )
    bottomSheetView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help( this method hide status bar and navigation bar on my main screen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check parent of container has padding too.
I can't see where is the problem from code or picture.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

The source code for BottomSheetDialog

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your answer so that it can be read on all devices, edited, copied as text, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to view and use your answer. See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help(